# Compiling separate modules in GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am really struggling to do what must be a very simple thing in GHC: I have a program that works and compiles fine, but when I split it so that part of the code is in a separate module I can't get it to work. The separate module is called FICutilities

> ghc -o FICutilities FICutilities.hs
>   C:\ghc\ghc-6.10.1/libHSrts.a(Main.o):Main.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to
>   `__stginit_ZCMain'
>   C:\ghc\ghc-6.10.1/libHSrts.a(Main.o):Main.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to`
>   ZCMain_main_closure'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

As far as I can see this is because there is no main function, but I don't want one in this module. I am using version 6.10.1 because I can't get more recent ones to work.

Please can someone help?! Thanks, Clare.

Comment: You shouldn't be using GHC 6.10, many libraries will not work with it afaik

Answer (score 3):

Just add `-c` switch.

However, you shouldn't build modules yourself: the recommended way of building is by using Cabal.

Other ways are:

1. `ghc --make Main.hs` builds main and its dependencies recompiling as necessary.
2. `ghc -M Main.hs` parses the imports recursively and generates a makefile with dependencies so you can use this information in your build system.

Neither http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/modes.html nor http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/modes.html#make-mode say `--make` is deprecated. It's not recommended if Cabal is a viable option. A big project is a pain to maintain without Cabal. Some tools in Haskell toolchain have plugins for Cabal (e.g. UUAGC attribute grammar preprocessor and others).

Comment: This tutorial will show you how to use Cabal. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program

Comment: I was told that the --make flag was deprecated and can be removed. Is that true?

Comment: @kqr: The `--make` flag is now the default, so it can be omitted, but the flag itself doesn't seem to be deprecated (see nponeccop's link to the GHC docs).  This was not true back in GHC 6.10, though.